# Why is Muzan impersonating a human?

Tags: demon-slayer

I just watched the Demon Slayer anime and have some questions:

1. Has Muzan ever been a human before?
2. Why is Muzan impersonating a human?
3. When Muzan was disguised as a child in Season 2, why weren't their parents suspicious when Muzan disappeared for a few days?

Comment: I am having a hard time getting your third question? Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes you remember SS2 EP. Akaza is scolded by Muzan at library room. Muzan are child.
and What will a parent do if their child ( Muzan ) is missing for several days?

Comment: It's no problem for adults ( Muzan SS1 )  to claim to work.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean - Muzan's parents should have been concerned about their child going missing for several days, but they weren't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, Muzan was a human. He turned into a demon nearly thousand years ago. Stated by Sakonji Urokodaki in Chapter 11 Page 2
   [image]
2. The reason Muzan disguises as Human, is to conceal his true identity from demon slayers. So Hashiras were shocked to hear that Tanjiro Muzan and had no clue on how Muzan was actually like (Chapter 46):

[image]

3. Well, Muzan can easily brainwash people and shapeshift into whatever he likes, he must have done the same in order to get into the child's family, and when he's done with the disguise, he might have altered the family's memory into thinking they never had a child.

Answer (score 3):

> Has Muzan ever been a human before?

A millennium ago, during the Heian Era, Muzan was turned into a demon during an experimental treatment trying to cure his terminal illness and his goal since then was to live without the fear of death and become truly eternal.

> Why is Muzan impersonating a human?

Muzan is impersonating humans and blend in with human society to create networks for information gathering and to secure funding using the different identities he assumed, without the humans he commands and manipulates being aware he is a demon at all. He don't want to be in the demon form roaming in the streets and while in human form, he can keep his identity a secret.

> When Muzan was disguised as a child in Season 2, why weren't their parents suspicious when Muzan disappeared for a few days?

In the latest cover identity, he became a sickly son to an old couple. Muzan has the ability to manipulate and erase human memories. So, he altered the memories of the parents into thinking that they had a son. Once his work is done, he can erase the memories. Even if they become suspicious, he can erase their memories or manipulate them to commit suicide (just like he did with his previous five wives) to avoid suspicion of killing. But I believe he can only move outside in the nights and he always keep his door locked, so I don't think the parents are aware of his whereabouts (they know he can't go outside without parents help).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Muzan had actually been a human before, but since then he has survived by eating humans.
2. Muzan is literally the leader of the demons. He has to be safe from all threats (from his perspective). He impersonates a human so that he can get adequate time for his experiments. Also, the Demon Slayers would have a hard time finding Muzan impersonating a human. Also, he has enough access to humans when he is living with them. He has enough food around him.
3. About this question, I'm not so sure, I will rewatch that arc of *Demon Slayer* and then answer your question.